# Finding measure of skewness for binomial distribution

Tags: probability, proof-writing

Here's how it was done in my class:

$E[(X)_3]= n(n-1)(n-2) p^3$ (Calculated using definition. I understand that part properly.)

$E[(X)_2]= n(n-1)p^2$ (Calculated using definition again).

Now, here's my first doubt. In the next step, it's written: $\mu_2' =E(X^2)= E[(X)_2]+E[(X)_1]= n(n-1)p^2 +np $

But isn't $\mu_2'=E[(X_2)]$, the 2nd order RAW moment? And isn't $\mu_2= E[(X^2)]$, the 2nd order CENTRAL moment?

I have the same confusion regarding $\mu_3'$ too. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusion stems from a misunderstanding of what "raw" and "central" moment refer to:  a raw moment is $$\mathrm{E}[X^k],$$ whereas a central moment is $$\mathrm{E}[(X-\mathrm{E}[X])^k],$$ where "central" refers to having the expectation *centered* about the mean.  The quantity you write $$\mathrm{E}[(X)_k] = \mathrm{E}[X(X-1)\ldots(X-k+1)]$$ is more familiarly known as the "factorial" moment.

Comment: Ok, thanks! So what do $\mu'$ and $\mu$ denote then? Raw and central moments?

Comment: Yes, although such notation may not be universally used.  $\mu'_k = \mathrm{E}[X^k]$, and $\mu_k = \mathrm{E}[(X-\mathrm{E}[X])^k]$.